# How to program an FMC if the database is missing the arrival airport?

Tags: navigation, boeing-737, flight-simulator, fms

Let's say you are in a 737 flying to [Geita, Tanzania](https://www.world-airport-codes.com/tanzania/geita-2536.html), as you can see this little airport/airstrip has an IATA code, but not an assigned ICAO code. What should you enter into the FMC if I want to fly to that airport?

And in general, how to navigate to an airstrip that has only an IATA code?

Comment: Just enter lat long.  The rest is the same.

Comment: You want to fly a 737 into a 2000 m x 22 m dirt strip? I'm pretty certain that Geita airport is VFR only, so if you were flying there as IFR, you would fly to a nearby navigation aid and then continue VFR.

Comment: It is about the FMC, I just picked a random airport

Comment: As I say, just enter the last navaid on your planned route, then lat long for the airport.

Comment: @J.Hougaard lol

Comment: @J.Hougaard -- 737s operate out of runways that size all the time *points over at KMDW* (although you are right that Geita's likely VFR only...)

Comment: @J.Hougaard, 2000 m runway is plenty for the smaller 737 variants (not for -900 though) and with track 5.75 m, 22 m width should be enough too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the arrival is missing:

[image]

If the departure is missing:

[image]

And here are the affected items:

[image]

Source: 787 FCOM.